# How to use backspace in vim replacement command?

Tags: vim, backspace

I have the below vim line:
`# do show int^H ^H^H ^H^H ^Hrun int eth 0/7`
I need to replace ^H with backspace to the the output as
`# do run int eth 0/7`
I tried `:%s/<crtl+v crtl+H>/\b/g`, the command is not working as expected.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace the literal ^H with the backspace character?

Try

```
:%s/\^H/\b/g
```

What you have currently is to replace the backspace character with the backspace character.

Comment: Did you try? It is not working for me. Moreover <ctrl+v ctrl+h> has to be given without backslash to search for the junk ^H in vim. ^H in vim which is an output of tee, represents the backslash we use.

Comment: I tested it and it worked, but for the literal string ^H, not the representation of backspace. I assumed that's what you wanted since the solution you already tried should work if that's not the case.

Comment: What's the file format of your vim? If it's dos, try running dos2unix on the file first and then trying your original solution again.